# TeXnicCenter text cursor appearance customization

Tags: texniccenter

Can the appearance of TeXnicCenter's text cursor be customized within TeXnicCenter's settings?  I use a Windows-level text cursor indicator to improve visibility, but it is not inherited by TeXnicCenter, evidently.